# Can we pass null to sql parameter to query all?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a query as follows

```
select * from table where col1 = @param1 and col2 = @parm2
```

And another

```
select * from table where col1 = @param1
```

Is it possible do both operations in same query based on parameter passed, if it is null query all or when parameter has value select them.

My queries are very big and i have to create 2 versions of sp's for each and i was thinking that  can i try to avoid creating two.

Comment: Using isnull or coalesce may cause table scans on your table.  Testing the impact of this is going to be crucial and may sway your decision depending on your environment.

Comment: Very true. The choice between "simpler code" and performance should not be taken lightly.

Comment: agreed and i tested both and keeping them separate  and they run faster than using isnull, coalesce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * from table where col1 = @param1 and col2 = isnull(@parm2, col2)
```

ought to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try this, but I don't think it will be very performant:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col1 = @param1 AND col2 = ISNULL(@parm2, col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
    select * from table where coalesce(@param1, col1) = col1 
and coalesce(@param2, col2) = col2
```

Answer (score 1):

All the suggestions here about using COALESCE or ISNULL **will** work - effectively doing this:

```
select *
from table
where (@param1 IS NULL OR col1 = @param1)
    and (@parm2 IS NULL OR col2 = @parm2)
```

**But** you may need to watch out for parameter sniffing.  SQL Server 2005 does not have the OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN - you can mask the parameters into local variables in the SP to help avoid that or use RECOMPILE option.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select *
  from table
  where where (col1 = @param1 and col2 = @parm2)
  or (col1 = @param1 and parm2 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Stored procedures!

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

In your scenario. something like

```
if (@param1 = null)
Begin
 select * from table where col2 = @parm2
( 
End

else if (@param1 = 'something' )
Begin
(
 select * from table where col1 = @param1
End
```

reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx